# Adding lines to points with the same trend

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I have generated the plot using the next code.

```
    newdata1 <- expand.grid(age=seq(20,100,5), 
 type_survey=factor(c("SwiSCI","SHS")),TINAN14_imp1=seq(1,10,2.5))
newdata1$phat<- predict(m1,newdata1)

# PLOT
ggplot(newdata1, aes(x = age, y = phat,color= type_survey)) +
  geom_point(size=1)+scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue"))
```

m1 is a model that uses the variables defined in expand grid. I would like to include a line for each points that have a trend. I see that the model predicts this behaviour due to the structure of the  TINAN14_imp1=seq(1,10,2.5)  = 1.0 3.5 6.0 8.5  i.e 4 lines for each color. But how to joint these lines? I added geom_line() but In that cases all the points were joined, I need 4 blue lines and 4 red lines for each set of points.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need a column in your data frame that shows which lines to join. Maybe it takes the value "a" for all the top lines, "b" for all the second row lines, etc. Then put `group = that_column` inside `aes()`. (Maybe you already have that column? Maybe that's what `TINAN14_imp1` is?)

Comment: I think adding `group = interaction(type_survey, TINAN14_imp1)` inside `aes` should do it.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.